# Get the Intent that resumes the activity

Tags: android

Activity.getIntent returns the Intent that created the Activity.

Is there any way to get the Intent that resumes the Activity in the case where the Activity goes from onPause to onResume?

Comment: are you referring to navigating back from an activity you opened in your app and wish to know which one it came back from? See `OnActivityResult` and `startActivityForResult`

Comment: No I refer to the case where the Activity is resumed from a PendingIntent attached to a notification.
In that case the Activty may not go through the whole lifecycle : onResume is called first and at that point, I do not see any way to find out it has beens resumed from the notification.

Comment: what about onNewIntent() method of Activity? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Thanks Gopal, onNewIntent works perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to override Activity.onNewIntent which is called before onResume.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it add this code:

```
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Now this should be like this:

```
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
        "Notify", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "App name",
        "App message", PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, new Intent(this, Main.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for your feedback, I could fix my issue by overriding onNewIntent as @Gopal suggested.